# How precise control the total time of jssor slider?

Tags: jssor

I am making a slide, which comprises a plurality of pictures, the total number of the picture is changing, but always the same length of time, for example 10 seconds. I use the parameter $ SlideDuration and $Duration and $Idle can not get the above results.

Picture number change, sliding effect change, but the total length of the time constant, how to configure?

Comment: Define your total time, divide by number of pictures, use as individual times.

Comment: What does the 'total time' stand for? Do you mean the time moving left <-> right per slide?

Comment: For example: do 10 pictures of slides, with a total length of 10 seconds all finished playing. How accurate control of each picture playback interval?